# Problem with NDSolve and Sign

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, numerical-integration

If `c1` cnd `c2` are zero, the code responds very well; but if one of `c1` or `c2` is nonzero, the code doesn't work correctly.  I get the error

> NDSolve::ndinid: Initial condition {0} is not in the range specified by the discrete variable NDSolve`s$147246. >>

I think it's because of the `Sign` function.
Without the `Sign` function, the code works properly.
I would like it to work correctly, and also I would like to know why this code didn't work properly.

```
ClearAll[θ1, θ2];
m1 = 1;  m2 = 1; lc1 = 1;  lc2 = 1; l1 = 2; l2 = 2; Ix2 = 1; Iy2 = 1;  Iz1 = 1;
Iz2 = 1;  g = 9.81;  Im1 = 1; Im2 = 1; η1 = 28;  η2 = 28; b1 = 1; b2 = 2;
c1 = 0; c2 = 1;

τ1[t_] := 10;
τ2[t_] := 10;

u1[t_] := τ1[t] - b1*θ1'[t] - c1*Sign[θ1'[t]];
u2[t_] := τ2[t] - b2*θ2'[t] - c2*Sign[θ2'[t]];


m11[t_] := m1*(lc1)^2 + m2*(l1 + lc2*Cos[θ2[t]])^2 + 
           Ix2*(Sin[θ2[t]])^2 + Iy2*(Cos[θ2[t]])^2 + Iz1;
m22[t_] := m2*(lc2)^2 + Iz2;
V11[t_] := 0;
V12[t_] := (-2*m2*lc2*(l1 + lc2*Cos[θ2[t]])* Sin[θ2[t]] + 
           2 (Ix2 - Iy2)*Sin[θ2[t]]*Cos[θ2[t]])*θ1'[t];
V21[t_] := (m2*lc2*(l1 + lc2*Cos[θ2[t]])* Sin[θ2[t]] - 
           (Ix2 - Iy2)*Sin[θ2[t]]* Cos[θ2[t]])*θ1'[t];
V22[t_] := 0;
M = {{m11[t], 0}, {0, m22[t]}} + {{Im1*(η1)^2, 0}, {0, Im2*(η2)^2}};
V = {{V11[t], V12[t]}, {V21[t], V22[t]}};
G = {{0}, {m2*lc2*Cos[θ2[t]]*g}};
initu = q[0] == {{0}, {.1}};
initv = q'[0] == {{0}, {0}};
q[t_] := {θ1[t], θ2[t]};
sol = First@  NDSolve[{Thread[M.q''[t] + V.q'[t] + G == {u1[t], u2[t]}], initu, 
     initv}, q[t], {t, 0, 100}];

Plot[{θ1[t] /. sol, θ2[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

Comment: This problem is quite tricky, it seems to me.

Answer (score 5):

It's a good idea to include the error you got in your question.  It gives a clue and might prompt someone to investigate:

> NDSolve::ndinid: Initial condition {0} is not in the range specified by the discrete variable NDSolve`s$147246. >>

Now `Sign` is discontinuous and will cause `NDSolve` to invoke special processing of the ODE.  I suspect that the strange internal variable `` NDSolve`s$147246 `` is added to the system along with an event to implement the change in `Sign`.  Note that the message is helpful in calling this variable a **discrete variable**, which is just what one would need to implement the discontinuous changes in `Sign`.  (Normally one wouldn't expect to see an internal local variable, and I'm still undecided whether you really should.  It would have been nicer if the basename were not the single letter `s` but something like `Sign`, say.)

In any case, the problem is with the initial condition for `q`, that is to say, for `{θ1, θ2}`.  It defines `θ1` and `θ2` to be 1D **vectors** instead of scalars, so that `Sign[θ1'[t]]` will be a vector.  But apparently `NDSolve` thought `Sign` was going to be a scalar.  The mismatch causes the error.

If it is acceptable for `θ1` and `θ2` to be scalars, then here is a fix:

```
initu = q[0] == Flatten@{{0}, {.1}};  (* <--- N.B. *)
initv = q'[0] == Flatten@{{0}, {0}}; (* <--- N.B. *)
sol = First@NDSolve[{Thread[M.q''[t] + V.q'[t] + G == {u1[t], u2[t]}], 
    initu, initv}, q[t], {t, 0, 100}];

Plot[{θ1[t] /. sol, θ2[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Note:* It is not essential, but what I often do, especially when debugging code on this site, is to examine the pieces. The error message complains about the initial conditions.  Since I didn't write the code, one of the first things I'm curious about in `NDSolve` problems is what the ODE system actually looks like.  So I evaluate it:

```
 {Thread[M.q''[t] + V.q'[t] + G == {u1[t], u2[t]}], initu, initv}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first thing that struck me were those strange (to me) initial conditions for `θ1` and `θ2`.  I often do this sort of examination when I've written the code for my own system and it does not work as expected.

Comment: +1 For this nice way to examine what the ODE actually looks like!