# NDSolveValue::ndinid: Initial condition Sign[x8\$...] is not on the range specified by the discrete variable NDSolve`s\$

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier and persisting through 12.3.1 or later**

---

I've checked the question about [NDSolve::ndinid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243723/ndsolvendinid-initial-condition-sign-205-09925-13-1-0-01-t-is-not-in)

This is the equation(Sorry for the complexity of this equation) and it's already written by Piecewise and on the right side as Michael E2 mentioned. However, the problem still exist.

```
μm=0.67;
ks=0.28;
x2max=2039;
x3max=939.5;
x4max=1026;
x5max=360.9;
x7max=80;
kgm=0.53;
kpm=0.14;

NR[expr_]:=Piecewise[{{1,expr>0},{0,expr<= 0}}];
μ = (μm*x2[t])/(
   x2[t] + ks) (1 - x7[t]/x7max) (1 - x2[t]/x2max) (1 - 
     x3[t - τ1]/x4max) (1 - x4[t]/x4max) (1 - x5[t]/x5max);
q20 = m2 + μ/y2 + dq2*x2[t]/(x2[t] + k2max);
q2 = (k1*x2[t])/(x2[t] + k2) + 
   k3 (x2[t] - x6[t - τ2])*NR[x2[t] - x6[t - τ2]];
q3 = l1*(k4*x8[t - τ4])/(x8[t - τ4] + k5) + 
   l2*k6*(x8[t - τ4] - x3[t - τ1])*
    NR[x8[t - τ4] - x3[t - τ1]];
q4 = m4 + μ*y4;
q5 = m5 + μ*y5;
l1=1;
l2=1;

cond = {x1[t /; t <= 0] == 0.102, x2[t /; t <= 0] == 418.2609, 
   x3[t /; t <= 0] == 0, x4[t /; t <= 0] == 0, x5[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
   x6[t /; t <= 0] == 0, x7[t /; t <= 0] == 0, x8[t /; t <= 0] == 0};
pars={k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6,k7,k8,k9,k10,k11,k12,k13,k14,k15,k16,k17,m2,m4,m5,y2,y4,y5,dq2,k2max};
minPara = 
  Thread[pars -> {
     v1 -> 74.15520144717327, v2 -> 20.601402223057743`, 
      v3 -> 202.89918221914687`, v4 -> 124.79211581419787`, 
      v5 -> 2.4441045037299847`, v6 -> 47.960088480721915`, 
      v7 -> 9.272966935510649, v8 -> 55.015434647393015`, 
      v9 -> 4.369360890981919, v10 -> 2103.346395453384, 
      v11 -> 8.387912952673362, v12 -> 268.3929837388525, 
      v13 -> 33.53996289971859, v14 -> -3.224365183029838, 
      v15 -> 11.193999240900595`, v16 -> 33.05890696229195, 
      v17 -> 88.20748789196996, v18 -> -3.3751062489269783`, 
      v19 -> -3.673156600729279, v20 -> 3.8923944544765714`, 
      v21 -> -11.123011817112472`, v22 -> 31.8854734957005, 
      v23 -> 11.36136104963341, v24 -> 55.43326765393106, 
      v25 -> 9.250141726334826}[[;; , 2]]];

eqn = {
x1'[t] == μ*x1[t],
x2'[t] == -q2*x1[t],
x3'[t] == q3*x1[t],
x4'[t] == q4*x1[t],
x5'[t] == q5*x1[t],
x6'[t] == 
 1/k7*((k8*x2[t])/(x2[t] + k9) + 
     k10 (x2[t] - x6[t - τ2])*NR[x2[t] - x6[t - τ2]] - 
     q20) - μ*x6[t - τ2],
x7'[t] == (k11*x6[t - τ2])/(
  kgm (1 + x7[t - τ3]/k12) + x6[t - τ2]) - (
  k13*x7[t - τ3])/(
  kpm + x7[t - τ3] (1 + x7[t - τ3]/k14)) - μ*
   x7[t - τ3],
x8'[t] == (k13*x7[t - τ3])/(
  kpm + x7[t - τ3] (1 + x7[t - τ3]/k14)) - 
  l1*k15*x8[t - τ4]/(x8[t - τ4] + k16) - 
  l2*k17 (x8[t - τ4] - x3[t - τ1]) NR[
    x8[t - τ4] - x3[t - τ1]] - μ*x8[t - τ4]
   }/. minPara;

tauNDSolve[v1_, v2_, v3_, v4_] := 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn /. {τ1 -> v1, τ2 -> v2, τ3 -> 
       v3, τ4 -> v4}, cond}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, 
    x8}, {t, 0, 7}];
```

The error is

> NDSolveValue::ndinid: Initial condition Sign[x8\$...] is not on the range specified by the discrete variable NDSolve`s\$..

Is there any modification to make it work? Grateful for any suggestion!

Comment: There is probably some constant missing in the first DE, ``x1'[t] == *x1[t]``.

Comment: Sorry, it's μ * x1[t].

Comment: I think you should report it to WRI. I’m not sure “delayed” events (such as represented by your `Piecewise`) are supported. There’s nothing about it in the docs that I’ve found that indicate whether it is or isn’t. I was unable to get even a simple system with a delayed event to work. If unsupported, better parsing might give an error message to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your definition of `NR`. Apparently, Mathematica has some problems with these piecewise-like functions (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243723/ndsolvendinid-initial-condition-sign-205-09925-13-1-0-01-t-is-not-in) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88261/problem-with-ndsolve-and-sign)).

Try changing it to:

```
NR[expr_ /; expr > 0] := 1;
NR[expr_ /; expr <= 0] := 0;
```

This works for me in Mathematica 12.3 - I can evaluate it at say $(1,1,1,1$).

```
tauNDSolve[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't notice it stopped at 2.4 ...

Comment: That the computation fails at about 2.4 has nothing to do with the original issue raised in this question.  Instead, it fails because `0.14` + (1 - 0.3101385678220016` x7[t - v3]) x7[t - v3]` vanishes there, causing `x7'[t]` and `x8`[t]` to become singular.  This is an inherent problem with the ODEs for the parameters chosen.  Therefore, the answer above correctly identifies problem and provides an effective workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As [@bbgodfrey pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252650/ndsolvevaluendinid-initial-condition-signx8-is-not-on-the-range-specif#comment631591_252652), the DDE in `tauNDSolve[1, 1, 1, 1]` has a singularity at t = ~2.4. This is coincidentally near a discontinuity event due to `NR[]`, so I mistakenly thought that was the problem.  But with that cleared up, my original idea of turning off discontinuity processing works:

```
tauNDSolve[v1_, v2_, v3_, v4_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{eqn /. {\[Tau]1 -> v1, \[Tau]2 -> v2, \[Tau]3 -> 
      v3, \[Tau]4 -> v4}, cond}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}, {t,
    0, 7}, Method -> "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False]

sol = tauNDSolve[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I still think the error message, which contains internal local symbols, should be reported to WRI. That shouldn't happen.